Is the product of a right-invertible, an invertible and a left-invertible matrix itself invertible?
Suppose $B \in \mathbb{R}^{(n,n)}$ is invertible and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(n,m)}$ is left-invertible.
Is $A^T B A$ invertible?
I know that $A^T A$ is invertible. I've been trying to work it out using the pseudo-inverse $A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.
I've also tried using the Cholesky decomposition of B.

No. If $m<n$, then take $B$ an invertible matrix that sends some non-zero $x\in\operatorname{col}A$ to some $y\in(\operatorname{col}A)^\perp\setminus{0}$. You can always do that by completing ${x}$ to a basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Then for the $u\in \Bbb R^m$ such that $Au=x$ we have $A^TBAu=0$.

A similar argument proves that for all $A\in \Bbb F^{(n,m)}$, for all $C\in \Bbb F^{(k,n)}$, $$\min_{B\in GL(n,\Bbb F)} \operatorname{rk}(CBA)=\max{\operatorname{rk}A+\operatorname{rk} C-n,0}$$

Not always. E.g. $\pmatrix{1&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0}=0$ is non-invertible. However $A^TBA$ is invertible when $B$ is positive definite and $A$ has a left inverse.

How would you go about showing the latter statement based on positive definiteness?

@knods Let $L$ be a left inverse of $A$. Then $A^TBAx=0\implies (x^TA^T)B(Ax)=0\implies Ax=0\implies x=Ix=(LA)x=0$. Therefore $A^TBA$ is nonsingular. Over a field, every nonsingular matrix is invertible. Hence the result.
